# Self join when using more than 1 table

Tags: sql, self-join

-- BEFORE -- All the fields used in this self join comes from the same 'Prime' table :

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.column1 as column1b,
    b.column2 as column2b,
    b.column3 as column3b,
    b.column4 as column4b,
    b.column5 as column5b,
    b.next_column5 as next_column5b,
    b.column6 as column6b,
    b.column7 as column7b,
    b.column8 as column8b,          -- 
    b.column9 as column9b,
    b.column10 as column10b,
    CASE
       WHEN a.column5 > b.column5 THEN a.column5
       WHEN b.column5 > a.column5 THEN b.column5
       ELSE a.column5
    END AS TheStart,
    CASE 
       WHEN b.next_column5 > today() AND b.column8 = 0
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
    END AS TheEnd
FROM  
    prime a , prime b
WHERE
    a.column11 = b.column11 
    AND a.conper = b.conper 
    AND a.condtn = b.condtn 
    AND a.genass = b.genass 
    AND a.column3 IN ('A_B', 'A_nB')
    AND b.column3 = 'B' 
    AND a.prime_sum_c > 0
ORDER BY
    column11, column1, column2, column6, column7, column5
```

-- AFTER --

The `[column8]` field now comes from another table called `[OtherTable]`

QUESTION: How should i write down the new code in order to continue using a SELF JOIN and taking into consideration that we are now dealing with 2 different tables because of the `[OtherTable].column8`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the query to use `join` like this:

```
select 
a.*,
b.column1 as column1b,
b.column2 as column2b,
b.column3 as column3b,
b.column4 as column4b,
b.column5 as column5b,
b.next_column5 as next_column5b,
b.column6 as column6b,
b.column7 as column7b,
o.column8 as column8b,          -- from OtherTable
b.column9 as column9b,
b.column10 as column10b,
CASE
   WHEN a.column5 > b.column5 THEN a.column5
   WHEN b.column5 > a.column5 THEN b.column5
   ELSE a.column5
END AS TheStart,
case 
 when b.next_column5 > today() and o.column8 = 0
 then 1
 else 0
end as TheEnd
from prime a 
inner join prime b on a.column11 = b.column11 
                     and a.conper = b.conper 
                     and a.condtn = b.condtn 
                     and a.genass = b.genass 
left join OtherTable o on <<your join condition>> -- join with OtherTable here
where a.column3 in ('A_B','A_nB')
and b.column3 = 'B' 
and a.prime_sum_c > 0
order by column11, column1, column2, column6, column7, column5
```